# Using querySelectors with useEffect in React to modify HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I'm trying to *add a class* on load to an HTML element which is going to be rendered with a functional component in React. When I try to do this with `useEffect()` it doesn't work since the function runs before I can have access to the element and returns `undefined`. I've been researching this a whole lot and still can't find a solution. I'm trying something like this:

```
function myComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const el = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
        const firstEl = el[0];
        const lastEl = el[el.length -1];
        firstEl.classList.add("red"); // Add class to the first element with class .item
        lastEl.classList.add("blue"); // Add class to the last element with class .item
    }, [])

    return (
      <div> // We don't know how many items there are going to be, for simplicity here are three span's
        <span className="item">1</span>
        <span className="item">2</span>
        <span className="item">3</span>
      </div>
    );
}
```

This would be fairly easy in plain HTML and javascript, but I'm having difficulties making  the code inside `useEffect()` have access to the elements in the component.

**PD:** For simplicity, I'm setting the items as three `<span>`'s, but in reality the items are conditionally rendered and I do not know how many of them are they going to be. Also, I'm aware that you could achieve something similar using css child selectors, and I wish I could use them, the example I gave is just a simplification of the code to make the problem easier to understand, but in my specific case, I *need* to use javascript selectors and I also need a way to do it in ReactJS.

Comment: The classnames will be overwritten by React the next time the component renders. What effect are you trying to accomplish here? React assumes that it owns the elements that it's rendering, but this code breaks that assumption and will result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: @RossAllen Basically, I'm rendering some JSX conditionally and I may have a few items or a lot of items: regardless I need to set some specific styles to both the first and the last item and the only way that I've found this possible in my case is with js selectors (the specifics are complicated, but I'm not able to use css selectors or put all the items in a direct common parent element). Using vanilla javascript and html I was able to accomplish this. I understand what you said about React. Should I use something that let's me append `<script>` tags instead?

Comment: Why are you not specifying classnames when you are rendering elements. you know which one is the first, and which one is the last. add your desired class to them in JSX.

Comment: @KavianRabbani Sorry if the example is confusing, yes, in the example I do know which is the first and the last, however, in my real code I'm rendering items conditionally, they can be a few or a lot or with different properties that I'm also setting via classes, the problem comes when I try to select the first and the last with a common class.

Comment: there is nothing wrong either when you are trying to map through an array of items to render. the first filter the valid items to render, then map through them and check if it's the first or last with its index, in order to add proper className/

Comment: @KavianRabbani Oh wow... you're right! For hours I've been totally fixated on the idea that I **have** to modify the element via javascript selectors. By the way, the reason that I couldn't modify much of the HTML is that I was re-writing the styles of a table library that already came with it's own HTML structure, but doing it the way you said is definitely the correct solution. Thank you.

Comment: so please don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: @KavianRabbani If you'd like to submit the answer I'll gladly accept it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, your question is a simplified form of the situation.
You probably have an array of items and you are going to render them.
There is no need to select the first and last item in this way. you can simply filter the valid items for render, then map through them, finally add the proper className to the elements you want. you can find the first and last elements by checking their index inside the map.